# Not analytic in a small disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^{2^n}}{5z^{2^n}+1}$. I want to prove there is no disk $D$ centered at $0$ such that $f$ is analytic in $D$. I would like to say that the $2^n$-th roots of $-1/5$ ($n\in\mathbb N$) are poles of $f$ with order $1$. But I did not manage to prove that $\lim_{z\to \text{supposed pole}} f(z)(z-\text{supposed pole})$ is finite.

Is my guess correct about analycity of $f$?
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Yes, the $2^n$-th roots of $-\frac15$ are poles of $f$. Note that $(z-\text{supposed pole})$ is a factor of the polynomial $5z^{2^n} + 1$, so that term of the series does not blow up in the limit. If you can show that there are no other poles in the neighborhood of a given pole, you will have proven that the limit is finite.

Comment: But you should also notice that as $n$ goes to infinity the $2^n$-th roots of $-\frac15$ approach 1 in absolute value.

Comment: I don't get it. Suppose we demand $|z| < \frac{1}{10,}$   then $1 +5z^{2^n}$ is indistinguishable from $1$   as $n$  increases. I think the sum is analytic

Comment: The function is analytic in the disk of radius $\frac 1 {\sqrt 5}$ around $0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm  I'd enjoy seeing a proof of that.

Comment: Ah, I see my (stupid) error. I thought the poles converge towards $0$. It is $1$ in fact. I am interested in the $1/\sqrt 5$ too :D :D

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the series does not converge if $|z| \geq 1$. For $|z|<1$, $5z^{2^{n}}=-1$ implies that $1=5|z|^{2^{n}} \leq 5|z|^{2}$ so $|z| \geq \frac 1  {\sqrt 5}$. Hence, we cannot have $5z^{2^{n}}+1=0$ in the open disk of radius $\frac1  {\sqrt 5}$ around $0$. Of course, there is a point $z$ with $|z|=\frac 1  {\sqrt 5}$ where the term corresponding to $n=2$ is undefined. Can you now show that the largest disk in which $f$ is analytic is the open disk of radius $\frac1  {\sqrt 5}$ around $0$?